# Getting the exact display name of the metro style apps

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-metro, windows-10

I am using [PackageManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager.aspx) class to list the installed metro style applications in the system.

[PackageId.Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.applicationmodel.packageid.name.aspx) does not return the actual name of the package, Neither is [Package.DisplayName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.package.displayname.aspx). Package.DisplayName returns empty string. It does return display name only for Package.Current.

When I tried to use AppxManifest.xml, I could not get the display name from
Package->Properties->Displayname too.

```
<Properties>
<DisplayName>ms-resource:///Resources/AppStoreName</DisplayName>
<PublisherDisplayName>Microsoft Corporation</PublisherDisplayName>
<Logo>Assets\WindowsIcons\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
</Properties>
```

Where can I get the exact display name of metro style applications ?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a reference to a `Package` instance, you can get the Display Name using an interop method and the registry. Here's a complete example:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using Windows.ApplicationModel;

public class PackageUtil
{
    [DllImport("shlwapi.dll", BestFitMapping = false, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, 
        ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]

    private static extern int SHLoadIndirectString(string pszSource, 
        StringBuilder pszOutBuf, int cchOutBuf, IntPtr ppvReserved);

    private static string GetPackageDisplayName(Package package)
    {
        using (var key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(
            @"Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel" + 
            $@"\Repository\Packages\{package.Id.FullName}\App\Capabilities"))
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder(256);
            Shlwapi.SHLoadIndirectString((string)key.GetValue("ApplicationName"), 
                sb, sb.Capacity, IntPtr.Zero);
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```